# How to access a field?

Tags: field, ada

I have a question regarding how to access fields from another file in ada.

I have this one type that goes :

```
type Token_Type is (INT_LIT_TOK, IDENT_TOK, ASSIGN_OP_TOK, ADD_OP_TOK,
                   SUB_OP_TOK, MULT_OP_TOK, DIV_OP_TOK, LE_TOK, LT_TOK,
                   GE_TOK, EQ_TOK, NE_TOK, GT_TOK, EOS_TOK, IF_TOK,
                   PRINT_TOK, DO_TOK, WHILE_TOK, THEN_TOK, ELSE_TOK,
                   LOOP_TOK, LEFT_PAREN_TOK, RIGHT_PAREN_TOK, MAIN_TOK,
                   SUB_TOK, END_TOK);
```

Now I have another file where I want to do a comparaison to see if whatever I have is one of those types, so I did

```
tok = Token_Type.INT_LIT;
```

but it doesn't seem to like the second part of this line. Did I miss something on how to access fields from a different file?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out that I was supposed to use the package name not the type name to access it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your declaration of the type `Token_Type` is declared in `Some_Package`, and given that `tok` is of type `Some_Package.Token_Type`, you should type

```
tok = Some_Package.INT_LIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Some additional comments: You don't need to use the package name if there's a USE clause that mentions the package that will apply to your statement:

```
procedure Something is 
    use Some_Package;
begin
    if tok = INT_LIT then ...
end Something;
```

Or, in Ada 2012:

```
procedure Something is 
    use all type Some_Package.Token_Type;
begin
    if tok = INT_LIT then ...
end Something;
```

If you really want to include the type name, to make it clear to the reader what you're doing, you could also say

```
if tok = Some_Package.Token_Type'(Some_Package.INT_LIT) then ...
```

and you can eliminate the `Some_Package.` prefixes depending on what USE clauses apply.  Sometimes you may *have* to write your code this way, if the name INT_LIT is ambiguous and there isn't enough context for the compiler to determine that one or the other meaning of INT_LIT is impossible.